# Using for loop to subset data and create variables

Tags: r, loops

## Goal

I am attempting to use for-loops to do two things:

1. Create variables in a handful of data frames
2. Create new data frames from subsets of other dataframes

## Description

I have individual survey datasets on each state within the USA. I would like to merge them all into a single dataset for the USA, but there are an unequal number of variables per dataset. Therefore, I plan to create subsetted data frames for each state and then bind them together.

## Question 1:

**First**, I would like to create a variable within each state that will simply have the state name as a string. This will help identify the state once I bind it into the merged data frame. Here is an example of what I would like to automate:

```
vermont$state <- "vermont"
alabama$state <- "alabama"
...
texas$state <- "texas"
```

I have created a list of each state through which I can iterate:

```
statenames <- c("alaska", "california", "vermont", ..., "new jersey", "texas")
```

I am attempting to do this using a *for loop*:

```
for (i in statenames){
    i$state <- "i"
}
```

## Question 2

**Second**, I would like extract a specific set of variables from each of the datasets into new dataframes, which I can then bind together for a single dataframe.

I have created a list of variables that I want from each dataset:

```
variables <- c("population", "size", "income", ..., "education")
```

I am new to programming, and trying my best to use for-loops to accomplish this:

```
for (i in statenames){
    i.sub <- i[variables]
}
```

When I execute each of the two *for loops*, nothing seems to happen. No error messages. No variable creation. No new data frame creation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated~

Comment: whats your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1

```
    for(i in state.name){
    df = data.frame(state = assign(paste(i),i))
    assign(paste(i),df)  
    }
```

Q2

```
    variables <- c("population", "size", "income")


    for(i in state.name){
     df = data.frame(state = assign(paste(i),i))
     df[variables] = NA
     assign(paste(i),df)

    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late response - I really appreciate it :)